# Error: API request's result could not be converted to a JSON object:

Tags: javascript, web-development-server

> ```
> Error: 
>
> Uncaught (in promise) GET request to api/endpoint? failed with error:
> API request's result could not be converted to a JSON object: 
> <html>
>  ..some stuff here..
> </html>
> ```

So, I made a request to 'api/endpoint', and for some reason it says the JSON object could not converted. I then went to this 'api/endpoint' and did console.log(response) (//this is what is sent to frontend). The console.log in the backend was simply { userId: '..', name: '...'}

I am not sure why this is not able to be translated..?

Comment: ajex?...A few details to answer

Comment: Seems like... `return res.json(res)`. Check if `res` is json by printing any key. If it will return undefined. then it can be a string so parse the json using `JSON.parse`